# Plot data ignoring some X-axis values on Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to plot some data on **Matlab** using the following code:

```
x = [1 2 5 6 7 9]

y1 = [1 2 3 2 1 2]
y2 = [2 2 2 1 3 3]
y3 = [1 1 2 3 1 1]

plot(x,y1,'--.','markersize',20); hold on;
plot(x,y2,'--.','markersize',20); hold on;
plot(x,y3,'--.','markersize',20); hold off;
legend('y1','y2','y3');
xlim([1 9]);
ylim([0 4]);
```

And I'm getting the following result:

[image]

Note that I have no Y values for the X positions 3, 4 and 8, but the X axis is still showing these X values in the graph.

There is some way that I can ignore the positions 3, 4 and 8 in the X-axis, and show only the Y values for the X positions 1, 2, 5, 6, 7 and 9?

I can use the following command to 'hide' these positions:

```
set(gca, 'XTick', x);
```

But the gaps related to these positions are still there.

[image]

**Update:**

This is the graph I'm trying to create (it was created on paint):

[image]

**Note**: in my case, the X-axis just represents the IDs of some images, and because of that I just need to show the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the plot you want by first leaving `x` out in the calls to [`plot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) (so it plots against the array index) then altering the [`XTick`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_d0e51413) and [`XTickLabel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_d0e51535) properties of the axes (and adjusting the x limit slightly):

```
plot(y1,'--.','markersize',20); hold on;
plot(y2,'--.','markersize',20);
plot(y3,'--.','markersize',20);
legend('y1','y2','y3');
xlim([1 numel(x)]);  % Note numel is used here
ylim([0 4]);
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:numel(x), 'XTickLabel', cellstr(num2str(x(:))));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you need gaps between plot lines. If you wish no values to be plotted there, try replacing the values by `nan`. For example,

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

y1 = [1 2 nan nan 3 2 1 nan 2]
y2 = [2 2 nan nan 2 1 3 nan 3]
y3 = [1 1 nan nan 2 3 1 nan 1]

plot(x,y1,'--.','markersize',20); hold on;
plot(x,y2,'--.','markersize',20); hold on;
plot(x,y3,'--.','markersize',20); hold off;
legend('y1','y2','y3');
xlim([1 9]);
ylim([0 4]);
```

This will give a plot like this: 
[image]

Comment: Thanks @kedarps, but this is not what I need. Please, take a look at the updated question. I have included an example with the graph that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need [`stem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stem.html).

```
stem(x, y1);
legend('y1');
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help @randomir, but I don't think `stem` solves my problem. The gaps related to the X positions are still there, and I need to plot multiple values and I don't know if the `stem` command allows it.

Comment: @KelvinS, after updating your question, it's much clearer what are you trying to achieve, and `stem` is obviously not the way to go. But, just for the record, you _can_ plot _multiple series_ with stem: `stem(x', [y1; y2; y3]')`. To separate values in each group `bar` is also handy: `bar(x', [y1; y2; y3]', 'grouped')`.